# Custom Route Returns 301/Passing Variable from Input

Tags: customization, redirect

I'm trying to register a custom route to validate a groupon voucher code for a landing page. I registered the route in functions.php like so:

```
    // Adding Custom Voucher Route 

add_action('rest_api_init','register_voucher_endpoint');

function register_voucher_endpoint() {
    register_rest_route(
        'voucher',
        'verify/(?<voucher_code>)',
        array(
            'methods'=> 'POST',
            'callback'=>'verify_voucher'
        ));
}


function verify_voucher($request) {
    return $request['voucher_code']; 
}
```

I set the link on the form action like this

```
<form action="/voucher/verify" method="POST">
                            <h5 class="title">Please enter your 8-character Groupon Voucher Code to redeem your
                                purchase</h5>
                            <p>Note: You will have a voucher code for each product you buy on Groupon. For example,
                                if you bought 2 CBD sprays on Groupon, you'll have to enter 2 voucher codes, one
                                for each spray.</p> 
                                <input required="" class="branded-input margin-bottom" type="text"
                                minlength="8" maxlength="8" title="voucher-code" name="voucher-code" placeholder="Enter your 8 Character Groupon code">
                            <input type="submit" value="Redeem My CBD!" class="btn btn-color-primary btn-style-bordered btn-size-large">
```

When I click the submit button or go to the registered route manually, it redirects to the home page and the network tab shows that the 'verify' route returned a 301. The site is using redirection but none of the options include the custom route I registered.

Two main questions:

1. Why is this redirect happening?
2. How do I capture the code entered into the input field in the callback function?

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: Your regular expression `'verify/(?<voucher_code>)'` is not correct. Have a look [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_rest_route/#user-contributed-notes). They are using e.g. `(?P[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)` there's a P inside.
Another reason could be that you are missing a / before the verify. Try this:

```
function register_voucher_endpoint() {
    register_rest_route(
        'voucher',
        '/verify/(?P<voucher_code>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)',
        array(
            'methods'=> 'POST',
            'callback'=>'verify_voucher'
        ));
}
```

`[a-zA-Z0-9-]` defines the regular expression group for this endpoint.

To answer question nr. 2: check the global `$_POST` array. There you should have an `voucher-code` entry which you can access with `$_POST['voucher-code']`.
I'm not 100% sure my answer is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - although this didn't work, it's still redirecting :/